# jQuery css method won't accept function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so I created a function that has 2 arguments for the css method, I run it but the arguments are getting read. The width values work on hover off and on, but w/e value i pass through in the arguments are getting read

```
function growImg(targetClass, imgClass, growPosition, growVal){
    $(targetClass).hover(
      function(){
        $(imgClass).css({'width': '25rem', growPosition : growVal});            
      },
      function(){
        $(imgClass).css({'width' : '12em'});
      }
    )
  }

// Calling function here
growImg('.img-profile', '.profile-img', 'top', '25px')
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
$(imgClass).css({'width': '25rem', [growPosition] : growVal});
```

You can alternatively use [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions)

```
function growImg(targetClass, imgClass, top){
    $(targetClass).hover(
      function(){
        $(imgClass).css({'width': '25rem', top});            
      },
      function(){
        $(imgClass).css({'width' : '12em'});
      }
    )
  }

// Calling function here
growImg('.img-profile', '.profile-img', '25px')
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the JavaScript is creating a key called `growPosition` and assigning the value of `growVal` to it. The reason being that JavaScript objects can be created without adding keys in quotes. There won't be a way for the parser to distinguish between a new object with a key called `growPosition` and the variable `growPosition`. Try using the object bracket syntax:

```
function growImg(targetClass, imgClass, growPosition, growVal){
    $(targetClass).hover(
        function(){
            var customCSS = { width: '25rem' };
            customCSS[growPosition] = growVal;

            $(imgClass).css(customCSS);            
        },
        function(){
            $(imgClass).css({'width' : '12em'});
        });
  }

// Calling function here
growImg('.img-profile', '.profile-img', 'top', '25px')
```